# Patch returning null instead of comments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, react-redux

*Hi,
Im rather new to backend. I´m trying to patch a newComment to a list of comments but gets updatedTravelTips null. Where am I doing wrong? and which mongo _id should i target?
I know my database is a bit messy with nested objects...
this it how my users look like in mongoDBcompass:*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/moncj.png

```
const onTravelTips = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const options = {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        Authorization: accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      // neWcomment comes from a text input in a form
      body: JSON.stringify({ comments: newComment })
    }
    //countryId comes from selected country from a dropdown and stored in state
    fetch(API_URL(`countries/${countryId}`), options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
          console.log(data)
          dispatch(user.actions.setErrors(null))
        } else {
          dispatch(user.actions.setErrors({ message: 'Failed to add travel tips' }))
        }
      })
  }

  <form className="add-tips-form">
    <p>Choose one of your visited countries and add some tips:</p>
    <select value={newCountryId} onChange={(event) => dispatch(user.actions.setCountryId(event.target.value))}>
      <optgroup label='Countries'>
      <option value="" disabled defaultValue>Select country</option>
        {visitedList && visitedList.map(country => (
          <option
          key={country.country._id}
          // country._id gets the new one, country.country._id gets the countryid 
          value={country._id}
          >{country.country.country} {console.log(country._id)}</option>
          ))}
          
      </optgroup>
    </select>

    <input
      type="text"
      value={newComment}
      onChange={(event) => setNewComment(event.target.value)}
      className="username-input"
      placeholder="food"
    />

    <button className="add-tips-button" onClick={onTravelTips}>Add travel tips</button>
  </form>

const Country = mongoose.model('Country', {
  country: String,  
  alphaCode: String,
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', {
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  accessToken: {
    type: String,
    default: () => crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex')
  },
  visitedCountries:[ {
    country: {      
      type: Object,   
      ref: "Country",          
    },    
    comments: Array     
  }]
})

app.patch('/countries/:countryid', authenticateUser)
app.patch('/countries/:countryid', async (req, res) => {
  const { countryid } = req.params
  const { comments, } = req.body
  const {id} = req.user   
  try {         
    console.log(countryid)  // working, gets the country id or the nested object id depening on what we pass in FE
    console.log(comments)   // working, gets whatever we write in text input. *should it be so?       
    console.log(id)         // working, gets user id 
    console.log("comment",newComment)  // not working, return undefined      
    const updatedTravelTips = await User.findOneAndUpdate( {id, countryid, comments }, {      
      $push: {        
        visitedCountries: { comments: comments}        
      },      
    }, { new: true })
    res.json({ success: true, updatedTravelTips })
    console.log(updatedTravelTips) // not working, return null 
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Invalid request", error })
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.patch('/countries/:countryid', authenticateUser)
app.patch('/countries/:countryid', async (req, res) => {
  const { countryid } = req.params
  const { comments, } = req.body
  const {id} = req.user   
  try { 
    const updatedTravelTips = await User.findOneAndUpdate( {_id: id, "visitedCountries._id": countryid }, {      
      $push: {  
        "visitedCountries.$.comments": comments
      },      
    }, { new: true })
    res.json({ success: true, updatedTravelTips })    
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Invalid request", error })
  }  
})
```